# Function doesn't enter in the dispatch in React / Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm working on a personal React project with Redux and I've an issue. All my redux functions are working well except one. I want to load  all the requests into the redux. In requestAction.js, I have the first console.log but not the second from the `return function(dispatch)`. Have you any idea why ?

Thank you in advance =)

Here is my code :

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react"
import {connect} from "react-redux"

import {getAllRequests} from "../../api/requests"
import {loadAllRequests} from "../../actions/request/requestAction"
import {convertDate} from "../../utils/utils"

import Header from "../headers/header"
import HeaderPages from "../headers/headerPages"
import Footer from "../footer"
import AdminMenu from "../../components/adminMenu"

const AdminRequests = (props) => {

    const headerTitle ="Administration"
    const headerBreadcrumbs = [{value: "Accueil", link:"/"},{value: "Administration", link:"/admin"},{value: "Commandes", link:null}]

    const [displayedRequests, setDisplayedRequests] = useState([])

    
    useEffect(() => {
        loadDatas()
    }, [])

    
    useEffect(() => {
        
        loadDisplayedRequests(props.requests.list)
    }, [props.requests])

    const loadDatas = () => {
        getAllRequests()
        .then(requestsDB => {
            loadAllRequests(requestsDB) //My redux function
        })
    }
    //Construction de la liste des commandes à afficher
    const loadDisplayedRequests = (requests) => {
        requests.map((requestItem) => {

                setDisplayedRequests(displayedRequests => [...displayedRequests,
                    <article key={requestItem.id} className="profile-user-request-item">
                        <section className="request-item-header">
                            <p>N°{requestItem.request_number}</p>
                            <p>du {convertDate(requestItem.request_date)}</p>
                            <p>Statut : {requestItem.preparation_status}</p>
                        </section>
                        <section className="request-item-resume">
                            <p>Total</p>
                            <p>{requestItem.total_amount} € TCC</p>
                        </section>
                    </article>])
        })
    }  

    const showDisplayedRequests = () => {
        return(
            <section>
                {displayedRequests}
            </section>
        )
    }

    return (    
        <div className="root">
                <Header />
                <HeaderPages headerTitle={headerTitle} headerBreadcrumbs={headerBreadcrumbs}/>
                <section className="admin-container">
                    <AdminMenu />
 
                    <section className="admin-content">
                        <h4>Gestion des commandes</h4>
                        {showDisplayedRequests()}
                    </section>
                </section>
                <Footer />
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (store) => {
    return {
        requests: store.requests
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    loadAllRequests
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AdminRequests)
```

requestAction.js

```
import {LOAD_ALL_REQUESTS} from "./action-type"

export const loadAllRequests = (requests) => {
    console.log("requests action = ", requests) //Displayed
    return function(dispatch){
        console.log("dispatch") //Not displayed
        dispatch({
            type: LOAD_ALL_REQUESTS,
            payload: requests
        })
    }
```

requestReducer.js

```
import { LOAD_ALL_REQUESTS } from "../actions/request/action-type"

const initialState = {
    list: []
}

export default function RequestReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type){
        case LOAD_ALL_REQUESTS :
            return {list: action.payload}
        break

        default :
            return state
        break
    }
}
```

index.js

```
import {combineReducers } from "redux"
import UserReducer from "./userReducer"
import ProductsReducer from "./productsReducer"
import RequestReducer from "./requestReducer"

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    user: UserReducer,
    products: ProductsReducer,
    requests: RequestReducer
})

export default rootReducer
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem at heart is that you don't dispatch. You need to

```js
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    useEffect(() => {
        
        dispatch(loadDisplayedRequests(props.requests.list))
        // instead of
        // loadDisplayedRequests(props.requests.list)

    }, [props.requests])
```

Adding to that: What you have written there is not an action creator, but a **thunk**. It will only work if you have the thunk middleware enabled - and even then, for this simple use case it just does nothing extra that you need.

As a normal action creator, it would look like this:

```js
import {LOAD_ALL_REQUESTS} from "./action-type"

export const loadAllRequests = (requests) => {
    return {
            type: LOAD_ALL_REQUESTS,
            payload: requests
        }
}
```

Generally, I want to make you aware that you are writing a very old style of Redux here and might have been following an outdated tutorial. Modern Redux does not have string action type constants, switch case reducers, action creators or `connect` any more.
For a quick look at modern Redux, take a look at https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux and for a longer tutorial, read https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts

Comment: I've to admit I'm a beginner in react / redux. My project is totally based on the outdated tutorial and I'm close to the end, so I can't change all my redux. I've to do another project with more up to date process to master the new redux. 

I don't understand why all my "thunks" worked until now, and this one doesn't work. I did the same thing to load my products in the redux and it works very well. 
I don't know how to apply the ``dispatch(loadDisplayedRequests(props.requests.list))``:(

Comment: Probably you are using the thunk middleware, so it is okay - just a lot of unneccesary boilerplate. I'll add some additional info to my answer above

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try this as soon as possible. Have a nice day :)